# Breakpoints in node_modules

Tags: debugging, node-modules

I open the same Node.js project in PhpStorm Windows and in WebStorm Linux. In both cases breakpoints in my application code work. However, breakpoints in `node_modules` work in PhpStorm, but do not work in WebStorm.

What did I miss?

Comment: javascript debugging support in both IDEs is identical (WebStorm plugins are used in PhpStorm), so there shouldn't be any difference in debugging experience. Try comparing your settings for **Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Stepping** in both installations. Also, do you have any symlinks in your project path? Are node_modules installed in your project dir, or linked to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a dependency was present in several versions in the `node_modules` tree and the breakpoint was set on a version which was never executed.